# Page Navigation using MVVM pattern without using existing MVVM frameworks

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement MVVM pattern in my xamarin mobile project.

I have following files for MVVM

1. LoginView
2. LoginViewModel
3. BaseViewModel

Following is my `LoginViewModel`

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

        private bool isLoginIndicator= false;
        private string etUserName;
        private string etPassword;
        public LoginViewModel()
        {

            OnLogin = new Command(doLogin , ()=>!LoginIndicator);


            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IMessage, EventType>(this, RestApi.UI_EVENT, (sender, eventType) =>
            {
                LoginIndicator = false;
                if (eventType.status)
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.success, "Login done", "Ok");

                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(AppResources.failed, eventType.errorMessage, "Ok");


                }

            });


        }


        public bool LoginIndicator
        {
            get { return isLoginIndicator; }
            set
            {
                isLoginIndicator = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LoginIndicator");
                OnLogin.ChangeCanExecute();

            }
        }
        public string UserName
        {
            get { return etUserName; }
            set
            {
                etUserName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return etPassword; }
            set
            {
                etPassword = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }

        public Command OnLogin { get; }

        void doLogin()
        {
            LoginIndicator = true;

            UserRequest user = new UserRequest();
            user.userName = etUserName;
            user.password = etPassword;
            user.companyId = "CEE";
            user.appVersion = Constants.getAppVersion();
            user.osVersion = Constants.getOSVersion();
            user.deviceId = Constants.getDeviceModel() + " " + Constants.getDevicePlatform();


            new RestApi().userLogin(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));


        }
    }
```

This class usually makes a webservice call when `OnLogin` command gets fired from Button and broadcast the `Message` using `MessageCenter`

Now i want to navigate to my `MainPage` which is master page once the user is logged in successfully hence i need to navigate to master page when `eventType.status` is true inside the `Message Subscriber`

but i don't know how can i properly navigate to other pages according to MVVM pattern.

i tried to search on net and i found there are ready made frameworks available like `MVVMCross` and `MVVMLight` etc. But i do not want to use those dependecies and willing to implement navigation some other way if anyone can suggest

Comment: Application.Current.MainPage = new MyFirstPageAfterLogin();   it's not correct?

Comment: would it be a proper way to do this in MVVM pattern  ? not sure though :)

Comment: I don't know... I think you should send a MessagingCenter from ViewModel to View and in View use Application.Current.MainPage = new... but I am not sure. I don't know MVVM very well...

Answer (score 4):

MVVM says nothing about navigation, so basically every option will be fine.

The only thing against code like:

`Application.Current.MainPage = new MyFirstPageAfterLogin();`

Is that you now have a reference to a page from your ViewModel, which should not be what you want. That is why MVVM frameworks tend to implement a concept called ViewModel-to-ViewModelnavigation. With that, you can specify a ViewModel that you want to navigate to. Depending on the framework (or how they implemented it), they have you register a coupling first or use a naming convention. For instance; I like to use FreshMvvm, which does this by naming convention.

So when I want to navigate to the `PageAfterLoginPage`, I create a `PageAfterLoginPageModel`. From my ViewModel (or PageModel in Xamarin naming) I can now navigate to the PageModel, instead of making a hard reference to the page. This way, Page and PageModel are separated and I can easily swap out the View if I wanted to.

So, either use an already existing framework, or peek into their Github repo to see how they do it if you insist on doing it yourself.

Comment: Logic in there is pretty complex to understand and even there is no document related to it

Comment: It's not rocket science. [This is](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/master/src/FreshMvvm/PageModelCoreMethods.cs#L46) where a PageModel gets pushed. Just follow the methods that are called from there and you should see all the code you need. What is it what you are after more specifically then? I think I gave you a pretty good idea of how things are and where you could go from here.

Comment: Ya i know it is not a rocket science but the issue here is m new to xamarin and C#

Comment: Ok, so again; what are you looking for? Can you work with this answer? What do you need more?

Comment: need a simple way where i can implement my own navigation service

Answer (score 0):

With the latest tools do a File / New Project / CrossPlatform / Master-Detail.  The master-detail template is all MVVM, without using any 3rd party frameworks.  There are permutatations of native and forms.  Great for learning and exploring.

Healy in Tampa.

[image]

Comment: I dont see this option in my visual studio 2015 , may i know how can i get that template ?

Comment: Is your Xamarin on the latest bits?  Tools>Xamarin>Check for Updates?